# Error: invalid option: --with-default-names

Tags: macos, homebrew

This question is posted to explain why running the below command will generate errors as the command below (seen in many stackoverflow answers) is outdated.

Unable to install gnu-tar with command:
`brew install gnu-tar --with-default-names`

Returns error: `Error: invalid option: --with-default-names`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run:
`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

This command instead allows gnu-tar to be found and run before bsutar

With default names has been removed.

Please see:
https://discourse.brew.sh/t/why-was-with-default-names-removed/4405